# How to maintain timezones in multi datacenter replication of mysql

Tags: mysql

We want to do a new set up of multi-datacenter replication with mysql, but those are placed in two different time zones. In this scenario, is it correct to maintain a single time zone in all datacenters or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  UTC ie. the timestamp so that it can then be used for displaying correct time accordig to the timezone.

Whenever you are referring to a particular moment in time, **persist the time according to a unified standard that is not affected by daylight savings. GMT and UTC** have been mentioned by different people, though UTC seems to be mentioned most often.
?? Include the local time offset as is (including DST offset) when storing timestamps. ?? Store timestamps as UTC or epochs(number of seconds since 1970) without time zone or offset.
Include the original time zone name, so you can reconstruct the original time at a later point and display correct offsets if needed.

Please refer to below link, it is very helpful

[Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)